# A program to repel mosquitoes?

Tags: c#

No, I'm serious.

Recently, I read that when the PC's piezo buzzer is made to vibrate at a certain frequency the sound would repel mosquitoes.

Is that true?

How do I programmatically access the PC buzzer (not the speaker), in C# preferably?

I don't know about mosquitoes, but my head hurts like mad. Argh...!

Comment: Well to answer your first question... http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080904060145AAg55xi

Comment: Haha, if this is true, I'm gonna implement that right away! (Assuming the frequency doesnt give me headaches :) )

Comment: I had a box decades ago that claimed it would repel rodents with high frequency sounds. It didn't work for that, either.

Comment: This would be great for using my laptop out on my deck in the evenings, but chances are computer speakers can't even operate at the 'necessary' frequencies even if this did work. Try it out and let us know though! :)

Comment: Still, you might be able to use this to stop _youths_ from loitering in your vicinity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mosquito

Comment: Who cares about mosquitoes?  What I need is a program to repel managers, especially ones that want to add features at the last minute.  :-)

Comment: "Not a bear in sight! The bear patrol is working like a charm." *"That's specious reasoning, dad."* "Awwww, thanks." *"By your logic, I could claim that this rock keeps tigers away."* "Hmmm... how does it work?" *"It doesn't work; it's just a stupid rock!"* "Uh-huh." *"But I don't see any tigers around, do you?"* "Lisa, I want to buy your rock."

Comment: Hi Vivek, did it work? I mean did it work with mosquitoes? Please share your result ;) :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL",
EntryPoint="Beep",SetLastError=true,CharSet=CharSet.Unicode,
ExactSpelling=true,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]

public static extern bool Beep(int pitch , int duration);

Beep(500,1000);
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the Beep driver has undergone some changes in Win7 that may affect using it for this purpose: http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx :)

Comment: My dog just started howling, I only read the code.  Must be working.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can do this with an unmanaged call to native Windows code, as described in http://www.geekpedia.com/code118_Beep-In-The-PC-Speaker.html.

Comment: The link is broken (*"404 Not Found"*).