# Creating a heater application - use power in CPU, GPU, and other components to make heat

Tags: process, cpu, energy, overheating

This might seem weird, but I'm interesting in creating an electric heater out of my computer, that is program an application, that heats up my PC, and I need some help.

I currently made an application, that runs infinite loops on the GPU (using a little shader), and on the CPU cores, however I'm interesting in getting the ram going too, as well as the several output ports, so.. About the ram heating, just allocate, and start randomly accessing and writing using all 8 cores?

And what about triggering CD-ROM, floppy etc, how do I do this?

Comment: You're trying to write a virus that does this to its host systems, aren't you?

Comment: I have a much more effective implementation for this, based on a canister of Kerosene and a box of matches

Comment: +1 for the weirdest program I've seen yet.

Comment: I'll go with Pekka's idea, it'll also be OS-independent, portable and still be able to work on power failures.

Comment: @Pekka: Unfortunately, that is a run-once implementation :( If your apartment is cold two nights in a row, you're out of luck on the second night.

Comment: @controlfreak123: See a [weirder one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168783/a-program-to-repel-mosquitoes) then.

Comment: I don't know that CD and floppy will generate much heat (unless you have media in the drives - then you just read the same file from it over and over maybe?), but if you could get the hard drive spinning, that might warm it up a bit.

Comment: @controlfreak123: actually, I have used my laptop for heating during several lectures where the lecturer seems to love setting the air conditioner to a killing chills.

Answer (score 7):

How about heater with a purpose?  Just run [World Community Grid](http://www.worldcommunitygrid.com), create tons of heat while making your computer do valuable computations for science.  It runs the processors wide open, is stable, and isn't just wasting cycles.

Comment: I would want to +2 if I could

Comment: wasting cycles == saving electricity, iow the planet!

Comment: @leppie-- if he's just running an app to uselessly spin and create heat, then that --IS-- wasting electricity.  If you're going to do it, might as well have a purpose.  You're right though, best not to run the computer at all to save the environment.  On the plus side, WCG is doing calculations for solar and water filtering projects right now.

Comment: is heating wasting electricity?

Comment: but +1 for the idea :), and I'll surely join it

Comment: Prime95 is one of the highest-power workloads you can run on a modern x86, keeping both FMA pipelines busy most cycles.  It has a stress-test mode, but it also has a distributed-computing mode actually searching for new primes.  https://www.mersenne.org/download/  If that makes your fans noisier than you'd like (or you'd rather pay for power for a different endeavor), there are plenty of other distributed-computing projects.  Some that can use GPU horsepower instead or as well.  And of course they're crypto-currency mining; some can be effectively mined on CPUs or GPUs, unlike bitcoin.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) together with [LinX](http://www.google.com/search?q=linx+bench)/[Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/). Max out your settings. Make sure you have a strong enough PSU.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [How to stress test a computer](http://www.ehow.com/how_5108013_stress-test-computer.html) If your interested in making your own try searching for open source stress test software that you could modify to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

There`s a torture test option for CPU & RAM in [Prime95](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=103) that looks like what you want. As for the GPU, there is [Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) which achieves the same kind of stress.

The heat from the other components will likely be not relevant (unless you have something really specific like a physx card) if you stress enough your cpu and gpu imho.

Comment: For sustained use, Prime95 has a distributed-computing mode so you can contribute to math research by helping search for new primes of a certain form, instead of throwing away all that power.  https://www.mersenne.org/download/.  Some Prime95 blocks will stress the RAM as well.  Other distributed-computing projects can use your GPU, especially if you tell Prime95 to run on fewer cores.  (Especially good if with SMT such as hyperthreading so Prime95 can still use all your physical cores, with the CPU part of a GPU computation just sharing it.)